# Can one contract Chagas Disease from the region near the Galapagos Islands?

Tags: geography, tropical-disease

Many have speculated the cause for Charles Darwin's poor health, and the likely culprit has been projected as Chagas Disease. But let's not go down that rabbit hole, i.e. diagnosing Darwin's mysterious ailment. I'm just curious... ***Can one contract Chagas Disease from the region near the Galapagos Islands?***

Comment: The nearest land mass is Ecuador 730 miles away, where Chagas is endemic, so I doubt anyone would be willing to say it couldn't be there.